# Meteor Packages: How to use different CSS based on 'development' or 'production'

Tags: css, meteor

There are some CSS @import statements in our code that really slow down Meteor's auto-reload.

I would like to take these out, but only for development.

Inside a Meteor package, neither of the following variables:

- process.env.NODE_ENV
- Meteor.settings

is accessible.

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'a-package',
  version: '0.0.1'
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0.2.1');

  // ...

  if(???) {
    api.addFiles('development-fonts.css');
  }
  else {
    api.addFiles('production-fonts.css');
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am needing something similar. Thanks

Comment: Actually, we kind of did.  I'll write the answer below @Precastic.

Answer (score 1):

The best way we figured to do it was this:

When starting meteor in development:

```
`FAST=1 meteor`
```

Then, inside package.js:

```
if(!!process.env.FAST) {
  api.addFiles('raisal-dash-common-fonts-development.css', 'client');
} else {
  api.addFiles('raisal-dash-common-fonts-production.css', 'client');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However that is peculiar... did you get to the bottom of why you can access `process.env.FAST` & not the `NODE_ENV` property? It would be cool to be able to use `NODE_ENV` instead of creating one.